How do I change the size of awcodes TiptapEditor in Laravel Filament?
My problem
I'm looking to expand the field content to be atleast 2 columns wide and 2 columns in height. I'm looking to change the size of the content field in a RelationManager however I attempted the following things in a Resource as well with no result.
The code I use for my DataRelationManager.php:
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Resources\OnderwerpResource\RelationManagers;

use Filament\Forms;
use Filament\Forms\Form;
use Filament\Resources\RelationManagers\RelationManager;
use Filament\Tables;
use Filament\Tables\Table;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope;
use FilamentTiptapEditor\TiptapEditor;
use FilamentTiptapEditor\Enums\TiptapOutput;

class DataRelationManager extends RelationManager
{
    protected static string $relationship = 'Data';

    public function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('title')
                    ->label('Title')
                    ->required(),
                Forms\Components\Select::make('language_id')
                    ->label('Language')
                    ->options(
                        \App\Models\Language::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray()
                    )
                    ->required(),
                TiptapEditor::make('content')
                    ->label('Content')
                    ->required(),
            ]);
    }

    public function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('title')
                    ->searchable()
                    ->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('language.name')
                    ->sortable(),
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ]);
    }
}

What I've tried
All my attempts on changing the size of the content field have resulted in either errors or the size not changing.

I tried using ->modalWidth()
                TiptapEditor::make('content')
                    ->label('Content')
                    ->required()
                    ->modalWidth('7xl'),

But that resulted in the following error:
Method FilamentTiptapEditor\TiptapEditor::modalWidth does not exist.

I tried using ->maxContentWidth()
Inside of the TiptapEditor using MaxWidth::Full
                TiptapEditor::make('content')
                    ->label('Content')
                    ->required()
                    ->maxContentWidth(MaxWidth::Full),

Resulting in the error:
FilamentTiptapEditor\TiptapEditor::maxContentWidth(): Argument #1 ($width) must be of type Closure|string, Filament\Support\Enums\MaxWidth given, called in C:\Users\user\Documents\home\filament2\app\Filament\Resources\OnderwerpResource\RelationManagers\DataRelationManager.php on line 36

Which prompted me to change it to the string 'Full'
                TiptapEditor::make('content')
                    ->label('Content')
                    ->required()
                    ->maxContentWidth('Full'),

Changing the parameter to a string resolved the error but did not change the size.
Using the ->maxContentWidth() outside of the TiptapEditor and on the $form resulted in an error.
    public function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('title')
                    ->label('Title')
                    ->required(),
                Forms\Components\Select::make('language_id')
                    ->label('Language')
                    ->options(
                        \App\Models\Language::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray()
                    )
                    ->required(),
                TiptapEditor::make('content')
                    ->label('Content')
                    ->required()
            ])->maxContentWidth(MaxWidth::Full);
    }

Method Filament\Forms\Form::maxContentWidth does not exist.

I tried using ->columns() but that did not change the size either.
                TiptapEditor::make('content')
                    ->label('Content')
                    ->required()
                    ->columns(2),


I figured out how to solve my problem using ->columnSpan() for the width and ->extraInputAttributes() for the height:
                TiptapEditor::make('content')
                    ->label('Content')
                    ->columnSpan(2)
                    ->extraInputAttributes([
                        'style' => 'height: 500px',
                    ])
                    ->required(),

